# Mapping a set in Hibernate with a composite primary key

Tags: java, hibernate, collections

For reasons related to DB replication, I need all the tables in my DB to have primary keys.

Some of the entities in my application are defined like the following one:

```
<class name="Item" table="ITEM">  

    <id name="id" column="ITEM_ID"/>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />  

    <set name="images" table="ITEM_IMAGE">
        <key column="ITEM_ID"/>
        <element type="string" column="FILENAME" not-null="true"/>
    </set>  

</class>
```

According to the book *Java Persistence with Hibernate (Nov 2006). chapter 6, page 244*

> "A set can’t contain duplicate elements, so the primary key of the
>   ITEM_IMAGE collection table is a composite of both columns in the
>    declaration: ITEM_ID and FILENAME."

The problem is, that this way of mapping a set actually creates a collection table with no primary key. (only a foreign key to the father entity table)

Is there a way to use key-element set mapping and force hibernate to create the collection table with a composite primary key of the two columns? (I'm not interested in changing the set mapping to key/many-to-many which will create another sub-entity table ) Can someone explain this behavior?

Thanks!

[A related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/751829/630372)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Hibernate 4.2 documentation 20.6.1](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-collections-taxonomy):

> If you want SchemaExport to actually create the primary key of a <set>, you must declare all columns as not-null="true".

So, in your example, you're only missing the `not-null` on the `key` element:

```
<class name="Item" table="ITEM">  

    <id name="id" column="ITEM_ID"/>
    <property name="name" column="NAME" />  

    <set name="images" table="ITEM_IMAGE">
        <key column="ITEM_ID" not-null="true"/>
        <element type="string" column="FILENAME" not-null="true"/>
    </set>  

</class>
```

---

If it's not possible to define all of your columns as not-null, you may explicitly add an index to the table via the `<database-object>` element (see Hibernate doc about [Auxiliary database objects](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-database-object)).